# Geometry of the Hilbert sphere

Tags: hilbert-spaces, fa.functional-analysis, spherical-geometry

Let $X$ be the unit sphere in $\ell^2$, i.e. $X=\{x\in\ell^2: \|x\|=1\}$.  Let the metric on $X$ be the geodesic metric, i.e. $d(x,y)=\cos^{-1}\langle x,y\rangle$.  Call a set a ball-intersection if it is an intersection of closed balls with centers in $X$.

Does there exist a decreasing sequence of nonempty ball-intersections in $X$ with void intersection?

If we let $S_0=\cap_i B[e_i,\pi/2]=\{x\in X: x_i\ge 0 \forall i \},$ $S_1=\{x\in S_0: x_1=0\},$ $S_2=\{x\in S_0: x_1=x_2=0\}, \cdots$, then $\cap_i S_i=\emptyset$. But  $S_i$ for $ i\neq 0$ are not ball-intersections.

Comment: $S_n=S_0\cap B[-e_1,\pi/2]\cap\dots\cap B[-e_n,\pi/2]$, so it is a ball-intersection. 

Comment: @Anton. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think yes.  Your balls are of the form $X\cap S(x,r)$ where $x\in X$   and $S(s,r)$ is the slice
$\{y: \|y\|\le 1 \ \text{and} \ \langle x,y\rangle \ge r\}$ of the unit ball. Note that if $y$ is in a slice, so is $y/\|y\|$. The slices have non empty intersection because they are weakly compact.

EDIT: This argument looks OK if all $r$ are positive, but $r$ can be negative, so some further thought is needed.

Comment: @Bill. Fortunately, for my purpose $r\ge 0$ is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: @TCL, it works only for $r>0$.

Comment: @Anton. You are right. $r>0$ is what I need.

Comment: Good, then I won't think about the general case.

Comment: The idea works for closed geodesic convex subsets of $X$ with diameter  $\le k<\pi/2$.

Comment: @TCL: Diameters $\le \pi/2$ are OK as long as at least one has diameter strictly less than $\pi/2$. 

Comment: That is correct. I also observe that.

Comment: In fact, it is enough to assume that the sequence is contained in a closed ball of radius less than $\pi/2$.

Comment: I meant radius; not diameter.  All slices $S(x,r)$ should have $r$ non negative and at least one $r$ should be positive.